# How to assign state object to a different object when creating a reducer

Tags: redux, react-redux

In my `userSlice.js` file I've got the following:

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    Id: 0,
    FirstName: "-",
    LastName: "-",
    EmailAddress: "-",
    Approved: 0,
    UserInfo: {
      DateOfBirth: "-",
      UserId: 0,
      Id: 0,
      CurrentAddress: "-",
      Gender: "-",
      ContactNumber: "-",
      JoinDate: "-"
    }
}


export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state, action) => {
      state = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

export const selectUser = (state) => state;

export const { setUser } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

However, whenever I run `dispatch(setUser(testUser))` nothing gets assigned to the state. This is the `testUser` object:

```
const testUser = {
  Id: 1,
  FirstName: "Test",
  LastName: "Test",
  EmailAddress: "test.test@test.com",
  Approved: 2,
  UserInfo: {
    DateOfBirth: "-",
    UserId: 0,
    Id: 0,
    CurrentAddress: "-",
    Gender: "-",
    ContactNumber: "-",
    JoinDate: "-"
  }
}
```

Could anyone guide me in the right direction here? Is there any reason saying `state = action.payload` won't work but saying `state.Id = action.payload.Id` will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you cannot do that this way because of internal implementation of slices in redux-toolkit. It uses Immer to track changes applied in reducers:  (read more here https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#immutable-updates-with-immer).  To avoid this issue just create your state this way:

```
const initialState = {
    User: { 
        Id: 0,
        FirstName: "-",
        LastName: "-",
        EmailAddress: "-",
        Approved: 0,
        UserInfo: {
            DateOfBirth: "-",
            UserId: 0,
            Id: 0,
            CurrentAddress: "-",
            Gender: "-",
            ContactNumber: "-",
            JoinDate: "-"
        }
    }
}
```

and reducer:

```
setUser: (state, action) => {
  state.User = action.payload;
}
```